# How to change SQL-SERVER table column name encoding?

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, laravel-5.4

I'm in a project of creating a Japanese website using Laravel 5.4.

The database is SQL-SERVER 2014, 
and the name of columns in almost all tables are in Japanese.

The problem is 
in the result Laravel retrieves from those tables in SQL-SERVER,
the column names are in SJIS while the table contents is in UTF-8.

Is it possible for Laravel to serialize those SJIS column names to model properties without hurting the UTF-8 contents?

Or is it possible to change the encoding of the column name in SQL-SERVER?

Thank you.

[UPDATED]
I am sorry. Here is part of the returned.

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#226 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(App\Foo)#233 (24) {
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(7) "Foo"
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(9) "コード"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "部門"
      }
      ["connection":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(8) {
        ["�R�[�h"]=>
        string(2) "11"
        ["����"]=>
        string(15) "日本語テスト"
        ["����"]=>
        string(24) "ﾃｽﾄ"
        ["������"]=>
        string(4) "70.0"
        ["�啪��"]=>
        string(2) "01"
        ["������"]=>
        string(2) "01"
        ["����"]=>
        string(2) "01"
        ["�ŗ�"]=>
        string(1) "8"
      }
      ["original":protected]=>
      array(8) {
        ["�R�[�h"]=>
        string(2) "11"
        ["����"]=>
        string(15) "日本語test"
        ["����"]=>
        string(24) "ｱｲｳｴｵ"
        ["������"]=>
        string(4) "70.0"
        ["�啪��"]=>
        string(2) "01"
        ["������"]=>
        string(2) "01"
        ["����"]=>
        string(2) "01"
        ["�ŗ�"]=>
        string(1) "8"
      }
      ["casts":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dates":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dateFormat":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["appends":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["events":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["observables":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["relations":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["touches":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["timestamps"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["hidden":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["visible":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["guarded":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the attributes like

```
["����"]=>
string(15) "日本語テスト"
```

"����"

is in SJIS and cannot be converted to propery.

"日本語テスト"

is in UTF-8 and is readable.

Comment: I think it's possible with phpMyAdmin in the operation section if the table

Answer (score 0):

Look at collations, you can apply it per database and per column
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations

Comment: Thank you, but from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql), there is nothing about UTF-8 and as I mentioned above, the data in the returned recordset is in UTF-8 and readable, only the column names are in SJIS.